# How to Convert NaN to 0 at dictionary, python

Tags: python, dictionary, nan

I have some code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ 'sentencess' : sentencess, 'publishedAts' : publishedAts, 'hasil_sentimens' : hasil_sentimens })
df.to_csv('chart.csv')
df['publishedAts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publishedAts'], errors='coerce')
by_day_sentiment = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='publishedAts',freq='D'),'hasil_sentimens']).size().unstack('hasil_sentimens')
sentiment_dict = by_day_sentiment.to_dict('dict')
sentiment_dict_new = {k: {m.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): v for m, v in v.items()} for k, v in sentiment_dict.items()}
```

and the output from sentiment_dic_now is :

```
{'Negatif ': {'2019-08-27 00:00:00': 5.0, '2019-08-28 00:00:00': 2.0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 3.0}, 'Netral ': {'2019-08-27 00:00:00': 4.0, '2019-08-28 00:00:00': 1.0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 4.0}, 'Positif ': {'2019-08-27 00:00:00': nan, '2019-08-28 00:00:00': nan, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 1.0}}
```

and I want to convert nan to 0, so I try this code:

```
sentiment_dict_new = sentiment_dict_new.fillna(0)
```

but I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nan` values is not equal to itself, so you can do like that:

```
sentiment_dict_new = {k: {m.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): v if v == v else 0 for m, v in v.items()} for k, v in sentiment_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if a floating point number is NaN (not a number) using `math.isnan` or `numpy.isnan`. Iterating through all the key-value pairs in the dictionary allows you to replace all cases of NaN with 0.

```py
import math
for key in sentiment_dict_new.keys():
    for second_key in key.keys():
        if math.isnan(sentiment_dict_new[key][second_key]):
            sentiment_dict_new[key][second_key] = 0
```

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: Is this using a different dictionary to the one in the example code?

Answer (score 1):

`math` has a built-in function to detect NaN values. You can then easily define a helper function that can do this:

```
import math

def fillna(value, default=0):
    if math.isnan(value):
        return default
    return value
```

Your new dict then can be:

```
sentiment_dict_new = {k: 
    {ki.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): fillna(vi) for ki, vi in v.items()} 
    for k, v in sentiment_dict.items()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for obj in sentiment_dict_new:
  for key in obj:
    if obj[key] != obj[key]: obj[key] = 0
```